# mysql merge scripts to create table

Tags: mysql

I've came across an issue and I cant think of a way to solve it.
I need to insert country names in several languages into a table on my mysql db.
I found these links [link1](https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list/blob/master/country/icu/en/country.mysql.sql) (en) , [link2](https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list/blob/master/country/icu/de/country.mysql.sql) (de) etc but I dont know how to proceed in order to finally have a table looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `en` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `de` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  ...
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Why do you need it? Why not to use `country` table from the link?

Comment: I need it in many languages for a multi--lang website I'm setting up

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally figured it out so I'm posting to maybe help others.

I created 2 tables (country_en) and (country_de) and then ran the following statement:

```
DROP table if exists `countries`;

CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  id  varchar(2), el varchar(100), de varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO `countries`
SELECT country_en.id, el, de
FROM   country_en 
JOIN   country_de ON (country_en.id = country_de.id);
```

which creates the table `countries` and joins the other 2 tables on their common key `id`

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you another table design. Create `languages` table, and modify a little `country` table: add `lang_id` field and create foreign key - FOREIGN KEY (lang_id)
  REFERENCES languages (id). Then populate `languages` and `country` tables.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE languages(
  id VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE country(
  id VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  lang_id VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, lang_id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_country_languages_id FOREIGN KEY (lang_id)
  REFERENCES languages (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

-- Populate languages
INSERT INTO languages VALUES 
  ('en', 'English'),
  ('de', 'German');

-- Populate names from 'en' table
INSERT INTO country SELECT id, 'en', name FROM country_en;

-- Populate names from 'de' table
INSERT INTO country SELECT id, 'de', name FROM country_de;
```

...Where `country_en` and `country_de`are tables from your links.